# Strange usage of in_array

Tags: php

I stumbled upon this code:

```
in_array(($_GET['some_value']??-1),[])
```

and I'm having some trouble understanding it. My questions are as follows:

1. What does the `??` operator mean in this context? My experience tells me it's similar to null coalescing but I'm not sure.
2. What does `in_array` do if `haystack` is an empty array? Again, seems like it would always return `FALSE` but I'm new to PHP so I'd like confirmation on this.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if downvoters could explain why. These random downvotes don't help me fix the question.

Comment: google "php double question mark" - it IS the null coalesc operator. If the array is empty, in_array returns false... 
This is all documented... go to "php.net"

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I'm asking because I did Google it and wasn't able to find anything. If you want, you can add phrase your comment as an answer

Comment: `??` can be said as equal to `if(isset($_GET['some_value'])){$_GET['some_value']} else {-1}`
Visit [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) page available on PHP's documentation, scroll to the **Return Values** section.

Comment: @mwaseema I read that page, but I wasn't sure why someone would call `in_array` with a haystack of `[]` so I thought there must be some nuance I was missing

Comment: @Woody1193 there can be many reasons for the haystack to be empty. Arrays can be generated on the run with some conditions and loops. It would be helpful to see whether array contains something or it is empty. If needle is found it will return **true** and **false** otherwise.
Simply this can be said, If a haystack is empty you won't be able to find anything from it.

Comment: @mwaseema Haystack was hardcoded as `[]`. Ironically, this code was encased in an if-statement that, if true, would print a message saying the site was under maintenance and would then call `exit` so I think it was meant to be manually edited before updates were pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double question mark IS in fact the null coalesce operator, new in PHP 7:
http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php

in_array() will return false if haystack is an empty array, in fact it will only return TRUE if the needle is found in haystack. Read the documentation here:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 3):

That expression can be replaced with

```
false
```

calling `in_array` with an empty array as the second argument will always return `false`, so it doesn't matter whether `$_GET['some_value']` exists, what it is if it exists, or whether or not it ends up getting replaced with negative one by the null coalescing operator.

You can't find anything in an empty array. It's probably either a mistake or an attempt at obfuscation.